# How to add many to many extra pivot columns?

Tags: laravel, database, voyager

I have two tables products and orders which are linked by a pivot table order_product with the id of each table. But I also want to add an amout column to the pivot table. How can I do this with laravel Voyager?

Answer (score 0):

Easily just define it in your migration file of order_product and access it from relation function as bellow:

```
Schema::create('order_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('order_id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('amount');
});
```

and for example in your product model:

```
public function orders()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Order::class)
        ->withPivot('amount');
}
```

Comment: I mean inside Laravel Voyager